# How to write KQL to display each Log Analytic Workspace log usage on Azure

Tags: azure, kql, azure-log-analytics

I was able to run this Kusto - KQL query in a specific log workspace to find its billable log usages over the last 30 days.

[image]

But our subscription has hundreds of log workspaces.  Is it possible to write a Kusto query in Azure Log query to display each workspace and their total billable log usage number?

Comment: Untested but something like this might do the trick as you need to use the `workspace()` function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/cross-workspace-query `let workspaces = dynamic(["workspace1", "workspace2", "workspace3"]); // replace with your workspace names
union withsource=TenantId *
| where TenantId in (workspaces)
| summarize TotalBilledSize = sum(_BilledSize) by TenantId
| render barchart` use the `summarize` operator to aggregate the `_BilledSize` column by the `TenantId` column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of workarounds on your requirement, I found that it is not exactly possible to retrieve all the workspace, usage details under a tenant within a single query.

As @Niclas suggested, you can use [`workspace()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/cross-workspace-query#query-across-log-analytics-workspaces-using-workspace) function but this doesn't works for all the scenarios.

I tried filtering your query by `resourceuri` and it worked as below.

[image]

Instead of using query language, I would suggest you use `PowerShell` script which is shown below to get all the required details in a single attempt.

```
$subscriptions = Get-AzSubscription 
foreach ($sub in $subscriptions) 
{ 
Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId $sub.Id
$workspaces = Get-AzOperationalInsightsWorkspace
foreach ($workspacename in $workspaces) {
         $usage = Get-AzConsumptionUsageDetail  -ResourceGroup $workspace.ResourceGroupName -StartDate (Get-Date).AddDays(-30) -EndDate (Get-Date) | Where-Object { $_.MeterCategory -eq "Logs" }
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Tenant   = $subscription.TenantId
          Workspace = $workspacename.Name
            Logs  = ($usage | Measure-Object -Property UsageQuantity -Sum).Sum
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @jahnavi, I'll probably submit a feature request of sort to Microsoft on this.  This is a valid use case because orphan workspaces are created all the times by unintended Devs .... having this visibility in an easy manner helps with skimming out the fat when it comes to paying the bills.